# Barplot for two groups using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I know this has been asked many times before. However, I can't find the solution for my problem.

I extended the `mtcars` data set by a dummy indicating whether the car was sold or bought by a car seller (buy = 0 -> Sell, buy = 1 -> Buy) and the date of the transaction:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$buy <- c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1)
mtcars$date <- as.Date(c('2011-01-01','2011-01-06','2011-01-10','2011-01-20','2011-01-23',
             '2011-01-25','2011-01-31','2011-02-01','2011-02-06','2011-02-15',
             '2011-02-22','2011-02-26','2011-03-05','2011-03-15','2011-03-20',
             '2011-03-22','2011-03-27','2011-04-10','2011-04-25','2011-04-28',
             '2011-05-05','2011-05-15','2011-06-05','2011-06-06','2011-06-17',
             '2011-06-25','2011-07-05','2011-07-11','2011-07-25','2011-07-31',
             '2011-08-23','2011-08-25'))
```

Now I want to use `ggplot` to get a barplot with the monthly sells and buys as separate bars. However, I can only create a summary plot of all transactions:

```
mtcars$month <- as.Date(cut(mtcars$date, breaks="month")) 
mtcars$counter <- 1
ggplot(mtcars, aes(month,counter)) + stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="Bar")
```

How can I create the same graph, but with two bars for each month (one with the number of buys and the other with the number of sells)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the buy vector needs to be strings instead of numbers.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(month)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=as.character(buy)),position = "dodge")
```

[image]